# My html/css navigation bar hover function causes the list items to move out of place

Tags: html, css

i dont know why but i am having trouble explaining this so sorry if the title isnt what im trying to say. I have created a different kind of html/css navigation bar just for good practice, but i have come across a slight problem. As you see if you run the code below, when you hover over the nav items, the background color goes out of place, i would like it to stretch like it does in the image below, but it dosent, it overlaps! Thank you for the help! Heres the code and image! 
[image]

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body{
 background:black;
 /*background-image:url(../res/back.jpg);*/
 background-size:cover;
}
header{
 width:200px;
 height:600px;
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 border:4px solid white;
 border-radius:7px;
 margin:10px 0px 0px 360px;
}
header h1{
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:30px;
 color:white;
 font-weight:900;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:75px;
}
header nav{

}
header nav ul{

}
header nav ul li{
 list-style:none;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top:25px;
 position:relative;
 top:60px;
}
header nav ul li a{
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
 font-weight:900;
 text-align:center;

}
header nav ul li a:hover{
 background:#ADABAB;
 color:black;
 padding:5px 70px 5px 70px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Home</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DONATE</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

**See my comments in the css**

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body{
 background:black;
 /*background-image:url(../res/back.jpg);*/
 background-size:cover;
}
header{
 width:200px;
 height:600px;
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 border:4px solid white;
 border-radius:7px;
 margin:10px 0px 0px 360px;
}
header h1{
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:30px;
 color:white;
 font-weight:900;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:75px;
}
header nav{

}
header nav ul{

}
header nav ul li{
 list-style:none;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top:25px;
 position:relative;
 top:60px;
  
  /*added padding*/
  padding:10px;
}
header nav ul li a{
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
 font-weight:900;
 text-align:center;

}

/*
chaged from: header nav ul li a:hover

to:header nav ul li:hover

also removed the padding on hover

*/
header nav ul li:hover{
 background:#ADABAB;
 color:black;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Home</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DONATE</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Armyguy556 please check the checkbox next to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hqadcurt/

What I've done here is make sure the `<a>` is the same width as the list.

```
header nav ul li a{
    font-family:Impact;
    font-size:25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:900;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

If you don't want that jerking around on hover just remove the padding on the hover.

```
header nav ul li a:hover{
    background:#ADABAB;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `li:hover` instead of `li a:hover` and remove the padding on it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: black;
  /*background-image:url(../res/back.jpg);*/
  background-size: cover;
}
header {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 360px;
}
header h1 {
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
header nav {} header nav ul {} header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}
header nav ul li a {
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav ul li:hover {
  background: #ADABAB;
}
header nav ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Home</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>WELCOME</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DONATE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body{
 background:black;
 /*background-image:url(../res/back.jpg);*/
 background-size:cover;
}
header{
 width:200px;
 height:600px;
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 border:4px solid white;
 border-radius:7px;
 margin:10px 0px 0px 360px;
}
header h1{
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:30px;
 color:white;
 font-weight:900;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:75px;
}
header nav{

}
header nav ul{

}
header nav ul li{
 list-style:none;
 text-align: center;
 margin:15px 0px;
 position:relative;
 top:60px;
}
header nav ul li a{
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
 font-weight:900;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5px 0px;
}
header nav ul li a:hover{
 background:#ADABAB;
 color:black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Home</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DONATE</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Just changed the margins and paddings at some places. You were close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header nav ul li a{
    font-family:Impact;
    font-size:25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:900;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    display: block;
}
header nav ul li a:hover{
    background:#ADABAB;
    color:black;
}
```

See [Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v989w7fy/)

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body{
 background:black;
 /*background-image:url(../res/back.jpg);*/
 background-size:cover;
}
header{
 width:200px;
 height:600px;
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 border:4px solid white;
 border-radius:7px;
 margin:10px 0px 0px 360px;
}
header h1{
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:30px;
 color:white;
 font-weight:900;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:75px;
}
header nav{

}
header nav ul{

}
header nav ul li{
 list-style:none;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top:25px;
 position:relative;
 top:60px;
}
header nav ul li a{
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
 font-weight:900;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 5px 0px;
 display: block;
}
header nav ul li a:hover{
 background:#ADABAB;
 color:black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Home</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DONATE</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```